# Use gzip compression for OTF fonts on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fonts, gzip, umbraco, http-compression

How can gzip compression be enabled for served .otf fonts?

It's an ASP.NET MVC website (Umbraco, but I don't think it's relevant).

I'm using two .otf fonts from typography.com, that are served by IIS (locally or from an Azure website) without applying gzip compression.

I tried in web.config, system.webServer section to set the fonts as mimetype application/font-sfnt or font/otf.

Using the httpCompression settings from [ASP-NET-MVC-Boilerplate](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC-Boilerplate/Templates/blob/master/Source/MVC5/Boilerplate.Web.Mvc5.Sample/Web.config)

It works for everything but the .otf fonts.

Comment: Searching the same as mentioned at http://www.phpied.com/reducing-tpayload/.